# is there a way to make HTML redirect you to a link as soon as you enter a certain website (for a chrome extension)

Tags: html, redirect, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

im gonna make it to where when you enter twitter (any link on twitter's website) it opens a new tab which is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vE8CgwBYvEo

but idk how to do that. do you know? it's in HTML but i just started learning it and just got into programming.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, at the moment your question is a little too conversational. Please read the [help] and take the [tour] to get a better idea of how your question should be phrased.

Answer (score 0):

**BY CLICKING ON A TAG:**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">Open Twitter link</a>
```

**REDIRECT AUTOMATICALLY (AFTER A GIVE TIME IN secs)**

```
<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "3; url = https://www.twitter.com" />
```